# Must start TweetUi Kit in Fabric.with() exception in Android code?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Hey so I am building an app and trying to incorporate twitter feeds into the app, and I am using Fabric to do it. I have installed correctly and everything is building fine, but when I attempt to run the following, which is from the example at https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start TweetUi Kit in Fabric.with().
```

Any ideas??

```
package com.android.twitterApp;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.twitterApp.R;
import com.digits.sdk.android.Digits;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetTimelineListAdapter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.UserTimeline;



public class TwitterAPIActivity extends ListActivity {

// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.

private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "**********";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "*********";

private Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());

    setContentView(R.layout.timeline);

    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
        .screenName("fabric")
        .build();

    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
        .setTimeline(userTimeline)
        .build();

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The Fabric SDK separates functionality into modules called Kits. You must indicate which kits you wish to use via Fabric.with(). This is typically done by extending Android’s Application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = 
                   new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey",
                                         "consumerSecret");

        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

        // Example: multiple kits
        // Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig),
        //                  new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

More info: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

See the canonical sample app at: https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android